# How create property string in power bi custom?

Tags: powerbi

I'm developing a new custom visual with power bi and I'm creating new properties, but I don't know how to create string properties.

For color I'm using type: { fill: { solid: { color: true } } } and for bool I'm using type: { bool: true } .

Any help will be good for me.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use text type for string input in capabilities.json

```
"type":{  
            "text": true
           }
```